# starting and ending tags for the converted equations like $ symbol

Tags: equations

i am using rtf2latex2e application in windows 8.1 . it is working great.but i have small problem on working with that . i am not find the starting and ending of the equation from my .net application . kindly tell me any logic for this problem. is there is any way to place a symbol like $ at starting and ending of the tags

eg :

```
(121)3×11÷(1331)2=(11)?
```

```
(121)\textsuperscript{3}\ensuremath{\times}11÷(1331)\textsuperscript{2}=(11)\textsuperscript{?}

(121)$\textsuperscript{3}\ensuremath{\times}$ 11÷(1331)$\textsuperscript{2}$=(11)$\textsuperscript{?}$
```

is it possible 
kindly help me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for ways to (re)program the app `rtf2latex2e`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly `rtf2latex2e` does, but ideally it wouldn't be using `\textsuperscript` to typeset the superscript items of a mathematical expression. It should be using `^` (the "caret" symbol) for this job. There should also be just a single pair of `$` symbols to mark the start and stop of the expression, and *no* `\ensuremath` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
$(121)^3\times11\div(1331)^2=(11)^{\text{?}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the output you've shown in your posting is at all typical for what `rtf2latex2e` does with math expressions, you're probably better off hand-editing the equations rather than "teach" `rtf2latex2e` how to do a better job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
    rtf2latex2e applications used to convert Rtf files to latex files. when the are converting

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STIXGeneral}
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
(121)\textsuperscript{3}\ensuremath{\times}11Ã·(1331)\textsuperscript{2}=(11)\textsuperscript{?}
\newpage
\end{document}

Comment: sorry Mico, i am not "teaching" to rtf2latex2e. i asking for help to do that...

Comment: @MadhanSeeman - From the documentation of the `rtf2latex2e` app: "RTF is not a typesetting language and there is a pretty serious mismatch between the capabilities and assumptions inherent in the RTF and TeX formats. The resulting document will need some editing." In short, if the limitations of `rtf2latex2e` stem importantly from the limitations of RTF, *there is no way* around hand-editing the file to obtain satisfactory code.